# What is the difference between Intel XDK legacy container API and Intel XDK Namespace Cordova API ?

Tags: cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

In [Quick Links to API Docs and Developer Tools](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/xdk-doc-quick-links) page there are links of Intel XDK legacy container API and Intel XDK Namespace Cordova API.

I want to know what is the technical difference between those two.And some of the plugins are deprecated like this one

> This Intel XDK Cordova plugin and API has been deprecated. Please use the equivalent standard Cordova accelerometer plugin instead.

Does that mean I have to use actual cordova functions instead of intel xdk cordova functions ?

Sorry if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Many/most of the intel.xdk API's were re-implemented using Cordova technology, in the process some were deprecated for various reasons.  One common reason is that there already exists a similar Cordova plugin and there wasn't a need for duplication.

So I guess the short answer is yes, for deprecated intel.xdk API's you should use some other Cordova plugin.